# Why are browsing samba shares from Ubuntu (Nautilus) so much slower than browsing from Windows

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I have a samba share over the a vpn server.  Browsing the share takes 60 times longer from Ubuntu than it takes from Windows.

From a Windows 7 Virtual Box (and any other machine in the shop) it takes 3 seconds for a folder with 1000 files to appear.

Clicking on the same folder from Nautilus it takes over 3 minutes before the files show.

The network is the same.  The only difference is browsing from Ubuntu vs browsing from Windows.

This is the /etc/fstab entry from the Ubuntu machine:

```
//myserver/officeshared /mnt/myshare cifs noauto,username=myname,uid=1001,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0775,noexec,credentials=/etc/smbpassw 0 0
```

I'm sure the problem is Nautilus and not ubuntu because I can get a file listing in 3 seconds with:

```
time ls /mnt2/mckserver/McKelvey/ > ~/filelist.txt
```

Output:

```
real    0m2.223s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? In my experience samba is almost always slower on linux, it has improved over years, but Windows is still faster with smb.

Comment: @przemo I'm using version 14.04 LTS now.  However, I've been using Ubuntu since version 8 and have experienced the same in each version.  I've basically tolerated it, but I have a Law Firm that I'm trying to convert to Ubuntu and this is holding them back.  They can't tolerate the slowness.

Comment: That's why I use NFS. I'm guessing in this Law Firm you're trying to use Ubuntu as desktops and that you have Ubuntu as servers, if that's the case use NFS, it's faster then SMB between windows systems, but a little bit more harder to secure.

Comment: I just googled 'speed up samba', it's not a new topic :)

Comment: @przemo It's not just for the Law Firm.  It would be a consideration, but I had already tested NFS and didn't experience any improvement (some years ago).  I just tested it again and the slowness is the same.  There are a number of Windows PCs and Laptops in use at the firm, so, though it doesn't provide any improvement, it wouldn't be very feasible in this case.  Are you saying you can bring up a folder over a VPN (over the internet) with 1000 files in less than a minute using NFS.  Did you do anything special with Nautilus?

Comment: no, it's out of my league, good luck.

Comment: Perhaps nautilus is trying to download thumbnails or metadata for each file? Make sure `Edit > Preferences > Preview > Show thumbnails:` is set to "Local Files Only" or "Never".

Comment: @TheSchwa Thanks for the input.  It was already set the way you mentioned (Local Files Only).  I put never for both.  It still took over 3 and a half minutes to reveal the folder.  Are you able to open a VPN networked folder in from a different location with 1000 files in less than one minute on Ubuntu?  Again, the same machine in a virtualbox of windows will reveal the folder in 3 seconds.